# jQuery, changing the text of clicked element on toggle is changing the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of articles to display, but would like to let the user hide/show so they don't have to scroll too much...

what i have
HTML

```
<div class="article-header" >Article 1 - Thursday Sept 13, 8:30pm <span class="toggleMe" >( hide )</span></div>
<div class="myContent" >...the content...</div>

<div class="article-header" >Article 2 - Thursday Sept 15, 6:30pm <span class="toggleMe" >( hide )</span></div>
<div class="myContent" >...the content...</div>

ETC.
```

Javascript

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.toggleMe' , function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).closest( 'div' ).next( '.myContent' ).slideToggle( function() {

        if ( $( this ).html() === '( hide )' ) {

            $( this ).html( '( show )' );

        } else {

            $( this ).html( '( hide )' );

        }

    });

});
```

If I do an alert in the toggle function, to see "$( this ).html()", I get "( hide )",  so i assumed changing the html of $( this ) would change "( hide )" to "( show )", but it is changing the contents of the ARTICLE DIV to "( show )".

Example:

```
$( this ).closest( 'div' ).next( '.myContent' ).slideToggle( function() {

    alert ( $( this ).html() );

});
```

Thx.

Comment: what you actually want to do, mean you don't want to change the content just hide or show the DIV ........
or you want to change content of article div 
kindly make question more clearly explained.... what is the issue....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the slideToggle callback `this` refers to `myContent` element

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggleMe', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $toggler = $(this);
  $(this).closest('div').next('.myContent').stop().slideToggle(function() {
    //here this refers to the `myContent` element not the clicked `toggleMe`
    //you can also simplify it to
    $toggler.html(function(i, html) {
      return html === '( hide )' ? '( show )' : '( hide )';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-header" >Article 1 - Thursday Sept 13, 8:30pm <span class="toggleMe" >( hide )</span></div>
<div class="myContent" >...the content...</div>

<div class="article-header" >Article 2 - Thursday Sept 15, 6:30pm <span class="toggleMe" >( hide )</span></div>
<div class="myContent" >...the content...</div>
```

Comment: excellent - thank you - Im still thrown by the alert() test i did returning what I initially expected... but regardless, appreciate the answer - all works now.

Comment: it appeared to all be working, however, once the page loads, if i click the second or third (anything other then the first) article's "hide" - the toggle happens, then it immediately toggles the div to be visible again... however if i reload the page, a click hide on the FIRST article, it all works and subsiquent clicks on any other hide works too.. but it fails if i start on something other than the first... any ideas?

Comment: what is "i" referring to in your new example?
$toggler.html(function( i, html ) {...

Comment: @jpmyob that is the `index` of the current element in the jQuery object.. you can ignore it

Comment: CORRECTION: it looks as though one of my large tables was missing a close row tag, and this was the cause of the behavior described above. After tracking that down thru a couple tests, it seems to be working great now - Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

i got it the problem is you are linking things in line which mean the last element is **('.myContent')** and in function **$(this)** means **$('.myContent')**.

if you want to change the span text you have to assign span to a variable the perform html() on that variable here is the code...

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.toggleMe' , function( event ) {
    var spanBtn = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).closest( 'div' ).next( '.myContent' ).slideToggle( function() {
        if ( spanBtn.html() === '( hide )' ) {
            spanBtn.html( '( show )' );
        } else {
            spanBtn.html( '( hide )' );
        }
    });
});
```

I have also attached the source demo 
[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sbvtpp6/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the scopes - this code is working:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.toggleMe' , function( event ) {
    var self = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).closest( 'div' ).next( '.myContent' ).slideToggle( function() {

        if ( self.html() === '( hide )' ) {
            self.html( '( show )' );
        } else {
            $( this ).html( '( hide )' );
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirtzbruch/h36yp1xj/)